# Orphaned App in content database in SharePoint 2019

Tags: sharepoint-on-prem

We are getting issue regarding Orphaned app in our on-prem SharePoint 2019  production environment. The issue reads as below

> RuleName: Missing server side dependencies.
>
> FilterValue:Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.Health.ContentDatabaseCorruption
>
> Status:ERROR
>
> Explanation:[OrphanApp] App [e8a7131c-3920-4724-aec5-54755938b967] is orphaned in the database [SP19P_Content_xxx] on site collection [ba95adf9-0dfa-467f-a040-7690468accc2]. Orphaned Apps are not accessible, cause unnecessary resource and license consumption and may fail upgrade. Try to uninstall this App. App [e8a7131c-3920-4724-aec5-54755938b967] is orphaned in the database [SP19P_Content_xxx] on site collection [ba95adf9-0dfa-467f-a040-7690468accc2]. Try to uninstall this App. If the App uninstallation is failing, it needs to be unblocked before the orphan App can be removed.

The site collection is accessible and in use. So, we can't delete it. It looks the orphaned app belongs to some deleted subsite.

Appreciate any help on how to clean the DB and fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at AppInstallations table via SQL Server Management Studio.
In my case the mentioned Site Collection was already deleted (and removed from the recycle bin) so no chance to damage anything. So it was quite easy to delete the line with the matching App ID.

BUT KEEP IN MIND! This is *not* supported! You do this on your own risk. You'd be lucky to have a backup of the content database.